# How to reverse an Axis in Sencha ExtJS Charts?

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, sencha-touch

I have a line chart with x Axis being numeric and y axis being numeric as well. I want the y axis to be reversed so that higher values are at the bottom of the axis and lower values at the top. I looked at the API Docu and didnt find a config to reverse the axis or so. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

In ExtJS 3 there was a reverse config option to get this going. With ExtJS 4 you have to use workarounds.

For reverting the x axis values you could use the sorters property of the store connected to the chart.

But for reverting the y axis you have to convert your values. Here's a sample on how to achieve this: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?132148-What-has-happen-to-quot-reverse-quot-config-on-chart-axes&p=949699&viewfull=1#post949699