# ExtJS : Column Chart with negative values display error

Tags: extjs, charts

I am trying to display a column chart in ExtJS which contrains negative values.

I get this really strange wrong display :

[image]

All the values in the chart's store are negative and between -79 to -83. Yet the columns are displayed beneath the X axis. On the other hand these values are visible on the Y axis' range, so I am not sure what is the reason for that.

Someone got a clue?

Comment: Please add the code to generate that chart here. Preferrably in a fiddle on http://fiddle.sencha.com/
Without seeing the actual code, we can just do wild guessing.
My best guess is that your chart treats the negative axis labels as strings and the actual range of values for that axis isn't inverted.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what ExtJS version you're using, but I found this question from back in the ExtJS 4 days and apparently inverting/reversing an axis was supported in ExtJS3 and then removed in ExtJS4. As I can not find any information about reversing/inverting an axis in recent Ext6 docs, this probably means you'll have to multiply your values by -1 and just keep your labels as is.

[How to reverse an Axis in Sencha ExtJS Charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541386/how-to-reverse-an-axis-in-sencha-extjs-charts)